# Mapping in PySpark without RDD.collectAsMap

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I got two dataframes. One dataframe consists of `MaterialNumber` and `HierarchyNumber` (18 digits) and also almost 200 other columns, the second one is a mapping file consists of `HierarchyNumber` and `Description`. My task is to split the `HierarchyNumber` in the first data frame into 5 levels by (Level1-Level5) by specific digit numbers which I achieve by

```
df = df_material.withColumn("Level1", substring(col("HierarchyNumber"), 1, 3)) \
.withColumn("Level2", substring(col("HierarchyNumber"), 1, 6)) \
.withColumn("Level3", substring(col("HierarchyNumber"), 1, 10)) \
.withColumn("Level4", substring(col("HierarchyNumber"), 1, 14)) \
.withColumn("Level5", col("HierarchyNumber"))
```

and now what I would like to do it to replace substring of digit codes like 3-digit codes for Level 1, 6 digit codes for Level 2 with appropriate `Description` from second dataframe. I've always used `RDD.collectAsMap` but its not whitelisted and I need another solution using PySpark. Any suggestions, please?

The first table looks like that

| materialnumber | hierarchynumber | col3 | ..col100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001915762470792000 |  |  |
| 2 | 003411831611043000 |  |  |
| 3 | 002653955128061000 |  |  |

After my initial transformation

| materialnumber | hierarchynumber | L1 | L2 | L3 | L4 | L5 | ..col100 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001915762470792000 | 001 | 001915 | 0019157624 | 00191576247079 | 001915762470792000 |  |
| 2 | 003411831611043000 | 003 | 003411 | 0034118316 | 00341183161104 | 003411831611043000 |  |
| 3 | 002653955128061000 | 002 | 002653 | 0026539551 | 00265395512806 | 002653955128061000 |  |

Mappings dataframe (df2) looks like that

| hierarchynumber | description |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | brand |
| 002 | subbrand |
| 001915 | entity |
|  |  |

and so on. And then I want to replace the digits from L1-L5 with its description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join `df2` with `df` for each level like this:

```
# we use coalesce and a left join to fetch the description if it exists,
# keep the number otherwise
# If all numbers have a description, you may omit coalesce and use an inner join
for i in range(1, 6):
    level = f'Level{i}'
    renamed_df2 = df2.withColumnRenamed('hierarchynumber', level)
    df = df.join(renamed_df2, f'Level{i}', "left")\
           .withColumn(level, coalesce(col('description'), col(level)))\
           .drop('description')

df.show()
```

```
+------------------+--------------+----------+------+--------+--------------+------------------+
|            Level5|        Level4|    Level3|Level2|  Level1|materialnumber|   hierarchynumber|
+------------------+--------------+----------+------+--------+--------------+------------------+
|001915762470792000|00191576247079|0019157624|entity|   brand|             1|001915762470792000|
|003411831611043000|00341183161104|0034118316|003411|     003|             2|003411831611043000|
|002653955128061000|00265395512806|0026539551|002653|subbrand|             3|002653955128061000|
+------------------+--------------+----------+------+--------+--------------+------------------+
```